# Using a variable within the FROM section of a Log Parser Lizard IIS log query

Tags: logparser

I'm trying to speed up my Log Parser Lizard queries to IIS logs on one of our servers.

This kind of query works but it's very slow:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM '\\myserver\c$\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex*.log'
ORDER BY time DESC
```

If I specify today's log filename that's a lot quicker:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM '\\myserver\c$\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex190731.log'
ORDER BY time DESC
```

I'm trying to find a way to achieve this without having to keep changing the filename within the query to match today's date. I can't find any way of using variables or functions like `strcat` within the FROM section of the query.

So in simpler terms, is there any way to inject today's date into a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 'C:\test\%DATE%.txt'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that LogParserLizard [supports inline VB.NET code](https://lizardlabs.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/66365-how-to-use-inline-visual-basic-net-code), specified using `<% ... %>` tags, so it was just a matter of inserting the date using that syntax and it worked fine.

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM '\\myserver\c$\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex<% return DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd") %>.log'
ORDER BY time DESC
```

or in my simplified version it would be:

```
SELECT * FROM 'C:\test\<% return DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd") %>.txt'
--converts to `C:\test\190731.txt`
```